# what is Querydsl 'Q'

Tags: querydsl

I saw an Example of Querydsl but I didn't understand what is QEmployee in that

```
QEmployee employee = QEmployee.employee;
QEmployee e = new QEmployee("e");
query.from(employee)
    .where(employee.weeklyhours.gt(
        new HibernateSubQuery().from(employee.department.employees, e)
       .where(e.manager.eq(employee.manager))
       .unique(e.weeklyhours.avg())
)).list(employee)
```

Someone please explain about '**Q**'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Q" classes are auto-generated query types, based on your entities, which are used for querying in Querydsl.

See here (section 2.1.5): http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e184

Comment: yes, correct. this class is generated through com.querydsl.sql.codegen.MetaDataSerializer , hence This Q'class' is used by querydsl internally to create the query or interact with db

Answer (score 4):

I see there is already an answer, but thought we should expand.  Querydsl auto-generates classes that represent your database objects.  If you have a table such as MyTable, the corresponding Querydsl object will get the prefix "Q" by default (QMyTable).  To query from that table, you simply need to instantiate an instance of the QMyTable object and then use querydsl to operate on that table (e.g., mysqlquery.from(qmytableinstance).list(myfield) ).

Q is just the default name prefix for generated Querydsl objects.  During Querydsl object generation, you can tell it to use whatever naming prefix you desire using the setNamePrefix() method.  Here is an example in a JUnit test that uses "NOTQ" instead of "Q":

```
@Test
public void testQueryDslGenerateCode_example() {
    Connection connection = this.getConnection();
    MetaDataExporter ex = new MetaDataExporter();
    ex.setPackageName(packageName);
    ex.setTargetFolder(new File(targetFolder));
    ex.setSchemaToPackage(true);
    ex.setSchemaPattern(schemaName);
    ex.setNamePrefix("NOTQ");
    try {
        ex.export(connection.getMetaData());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This JUnit test would generate classes that were all prefixed with "NOTQ" instead of "Q".  Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -3):

I think Q is just parameter or variable. Maybe you can change it with other char, ehmmm or it's symbol for call function the name is `Q` then follow variable `(Q+namevariable)`
like :

```
QCustomer customer = new QCustomer("c"); // alias for the CUSTOMER table
```