# Migrate ResourceSupport to RepresentationModel

Tags: java, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have this code which I would like to migrate to latest Spring hateoas version. I tried this:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransactionResource extends RepresentationModel {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private UUID uuid;

  public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    // Remove the hateoas ID (self referential link) if exists
    if (getId() != null) {
      getLinks().remove(getId());
    }

    add(linkTo(methodOn(TransactionController.class).lookup(uuid, null))
        .withSelfRel()
        .expand());

    this.uuid = uuid;
  }
  ......................
}
```

I get error Cannot resolve method `'getId' in 'TransactionResource'` and `Cannot resolve method 'remove' in 'Links'`

Do you know how I have to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in the newer Spring Hateoas version you could achieve a similar result with this code:

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransactionResource extends RepresentationModel {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private UUID uuid;

  public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    // Remove the hateoas ID (self referential link) if exists
    if (this.hasLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF)) {
      this.getLinks().without(IanaLinkRelations.SELF);
    }

    add(linkTo(methodOn(TransactionController.class).lookup(uuid, null))
        .withSelfRel()
        .expand());

    this.uuid = uuid;
  }
  ......................
}
```

I haven't tested it but probably the above code could be simplified like this:

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransactionResource extends RepresentationModel {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private UUID uuid;

  public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    // Remove the hateoas ID (self referential link) if exists
    this.getLinks().without(IanaLinkRelations.SELF);

    add(linkTo(methodOn(TransactionController.class).lookup(uuid, null))
        .withSelfRel()
        .expand());

    this.uuid = uuid;
  }
  ......................
}
```

Note that the main changes are related to the use of the methods provided in [`RepresentationModel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.html) and in the [`Links`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.html).

As I told, please, be aware that I haven't tested the code. My main concern has to do with the fact that `this.getLinks().without(IanaLinkRelations.SELF);` return a new `Links` instance and it may not replace *in place* the existing ones associated with the `RepresentationModel`, so you probably would need to `merge` the results. Please, take that into account.